# Why can't my JToolBar and JPanel coexist on the same JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jtoolbar

I want my Jpanel to be just below my toolbar but the result will be my jpanel not appearing and if I also make my JPanel to have a borderlayout of page start the JFrame will only show the JPanel and not my toolbar.
This is my code

```
package omok;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Omok implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame =new JFrame();
    public Omok() {
       JMenuBar menuBar=menubar();
       JToolBar toolBar=toolBar();
       JPanel panel=panel();
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setSize(400,500);
       frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
       frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
       frame.add(toolBar,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
       frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
private JMenuBar menubar() {
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Game");
    menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_G);
    menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("Game menu");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Play", KeyEvent.VK_P);
    menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
       KeyEvent.VK_P, InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK));
    menuItem.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
       "Play a new game");
    //menuItem.addActionListener(…);
    menu.add(menuItem);
    return menuBar;
}
private JToolBar toolBar() {
    ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\carlo\\Documents\\Adv OO Programming\\L\\OmokGUI\\res\\play.png");
    Image image=icon.getImage();
    Image newImg=image.getScaledInstance(20, 20, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    icon=new ImageIcon(newImg);
    JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar("Omok");
    JButton button = new JButton(icon);
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
    button.setToolTipText("Play a new game");
    button.setFocusPainted(false);
    toolBar.add(button);
    toolBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,30));
    return toolBar;

}
private JPanel panel() {
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,40));
    panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
    return panel;
}

}
```

This is the result I get
[image: Result of my code]

Comment: A `JPanel` won't be visible unless there are elements in it. Your `JPanel` doesn't have anything in it, which is why it doesn't show up.

Comment: As the [`BorderLayout` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) state, *"`PAGE_START` ... this is equivalent to NORTH"* - so you're trying to place two components into the same position, `BorderLayout` will only allow a single component to exist at each of it's 5 available locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [`BorderLayout` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) state, *"`PAGE_START` ... this is equivalent to NORTH"* - so you're trying to place two components into the same position, `BorderLayout` will only allow a single component to exist at each of it's 5 available locations.

If you want both components in the `NORTH` position, then you'd need to use another container (like `JPanel`) to place them into and the place that container into the `NORTH` position.

This is often know as a compound layout.